# How can I return ordered data from Firebase database with Node.js using the firebase-admin module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I'm trying to query Firebase database to get data ordered by timestamp.

**1: This works but the data returned is not ordered by timestamp:**

```
router.get('/articles', function(req, res, next) {
    admin.database().ref('articles').orderByChild('timestamp').once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
        let articles = snapshot.val();
        console.log(articles);
        res.render('articles', articles);
    });
});
```

**2: This returns me the data ordered by timestamp like I want (I can see it in the console.log), but I get this error:**

```
// /node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1003
//   if (err) return req.next(err);
//                      ^
// TypeError: req.next is not a function

router.get('/articles', function(req, res, next) {
    admin.database().ref('articles').orderByChild('timestamp').on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
        let articles = snapshot.val();
        console.log(articles);
        res.render('articles', articles);
    });
});
```

I don't get what I'm doing wrong. I see that the two firebase database calls are different, one is an **once** and **then** (so it must be a promise..?) and the other is a **on** (so i suppose it's just a normal callback...).

Do you have any idea on why is happening here? Sorry if this is obvious but I'm somewhat of a beginner..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

So in your first example `snapshot` holds they things: the keys of the matching nodes, their values, *and* the ordering between them. When you call `snapshot.val()` this data is converted into a regular JSON object, which doesn't have space for all three pieces of information. At this point the ordering information is dropped.

The solution is to use `snapshot.forEach()` to loop over the matching nodes in the correct order.

```
admin.database().ref('articles').orderByChild('timestamp').once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
  var articles = [];
  snapshot.forEach(function(articleSnapshot)
    articles.push(snapshot.val());
  });
  console.log(articles);
  res.render('articles', articles);
});
```